# Can you put new if statements into a child class from a parent class (probably phrased wrong)

Tags: python

So I want to have '`if Battle_Option == "E"`, do this in the `Battle()` class, but if its in the `Wizard_Battle()` class I want it to do something different, is there any way to do it?

I deleted the code a bit to only show important lines

```
class Battle():
        Battle_Option = input("What will you do? \n W.Attack \n E.Special 
        Move \n R.Guard \n T.Wait").upper()
        if Battle_Option == "E":
            print("You pick up your magical spear and yes")
```

```
class Wizard_Battle(Battle):
        def __init__(self):
            Battle.__init__(self)
        def Yourturn(self):
            global Battle_Option
            if Battle_Option == "E":
                print("You wizarded")
```

Comment: is that battle code inside a method in battle? or inside the class body?

Answer (score 0):

You can access it through `Battle`:

```
class Wizard_Battle(Battle):
        def __init__(self):
            Battle.__init__(self)
        def Yourturn(self):
            if Battle.Battle_Option == "E":
                print("You wizarded")
```

Here you have the [live example](https://repl.it/repls/WeeBisqueInsurance)

Answer (score 0):

If *something*  is to be specialized in a subclass, it should be a method that is overriden in the subclass:

```
class Battle():
    ...
        Battle_Option = input("What will you do? \n W.Attack \n E.Special 
        Move \n R.Guard \n T.Wait").upper()
        if Battle_Option == "E":
            self.e_battle()
    ...
    def e_battle(self):
        print("You pick up your magical spear and yes")

class Wizard_Battle(Battle):
    ...
    def e_battle(self):
        print("You wizarded")
```